# Cordova app: accented characters and CSS not working on every phone

Tags: android, cordova

I have a web app made with Cordova 6.

When I launch it on my OnePlus One, everything is OK.

When I launch it on a Motorola XT890, I don't have accented characters and some CSS properties don't work. For example **translateY** doesn't work with the Motorola and the property is struck out on Chrome inspector for this phone.

I thought it depends on Chrome version but it is the same on both phones (55.0.2883.91).

The Android version is 6.0.1 on the OnePlus and 4.4.2 on the Motorola.

Where does this problem come from ?

Comment: depends on Webview version, not chrome

Comment: @Eric Oh thanks, I didn't even know such a thing existed... So the Webview depends on Android version and can't be updated?

Comment: It's a separate App and it has its own versioning..

Comment: Yes but it seems it's related to the Android version (= API level), no? So if I want my app to display correct CSS and accented characters on the Motorola, I must make my code compatible with the webview used in Android 4.4.2, aka API 19, am I right?

Comment: Well, the official webview app only support 5 and up now. v4 has been deprecated afaik. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview

Comment: Wow OK, but 25 % of Android phones are under 4.4 :/ Thanks.

Comment: In Android 5.0 (Lollipop), the WebView has moved to an APK so it can be updated seperately to the Android platform, just FYI. In 4.4.2 I think it can't be updated.